# Shell Pay Script

Tags: linux

I'm currently studying Linux Programming, and we have been asked to produce a pay system.

Comment: what are you getting wrong? floating values not coming properly.

Comment: execute just the bits related to socialSecurity in your terminal window to see where it is breaking. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

It's often advised to to financial calculations in cents, to avoid floating point errors.

Your script is a great start. I took the liberty of polishing it a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i hrs=1
declare -i rate
declare -i grossCents netCents socSecAmtCents

socSecRate=5
currency="£"

function displayAmt {
    printf "%s%d.%02d\n" "$currency" $(($1 / 100)) $(($1 % 100))
}

while :; do
    read -p "Enter number of hours worked: " hrs
    (( hrs == 0 )) && break

    read -p "Please enter the pay rate per hour: " rate

    (( 
        grossCents     = hrs * rate * 100,
        socSecAmtCents = grossCents * socSecRate / 100,
        netCents       = grossCents - socSecAmtCents 
    ))

    printf "Payable Amount before Social Security: %10s\n" "$(displayAmt $grossCents)"
    printf "Total Social Security Deducted:        %10s\n" "$(displayAmt $socSecAmtCents)"
    printf "Payable Amount after Social Security:  %10s\n" "$(displayAmt $netCents)"
    echo
done
```

```
$ bash pay.sh 
Enter number of hours worked: 123
Please enter the pay rate per hour: 19
Payable Amount before Social Security:  £2337.00
Total Social Security Deducted:          £116.85
Payable Amount after Social Security:   £2220.15

Enter number of hours worked: q
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. The help is much appreciated